# How can I use the wdio.conf.js files to specify test folders of which e2e tests to run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I have an app that runs in various different modes. These modes change the UI completely therefore each mode requires a completely different set of E2E tests.

I've created different wdio configuration files for each mode, and attempted to specify the specs for each one as well, so that it only runs the specified specs. Unfortunately that isn't working.

So right now there are three wdio.conf files (all of which inherit from defaults from wdio.conf.js) and the following folder structure:

```
+--test
   +--specs
     +--browser
         +--modeA
            +--testFile.js
         +--modeB
            +--testFile.js
+--wdio.conf.js
|
+--wdio.conf.modeA.js
|
+--wdio.conf.modeB.js
```

I've created npm commands for each mode, which are as follows:

```
// (package.json)
...
"tools:e2e": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio/wdio.conf.js",
"tools:e2e:modeA": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio/wdio.conf.modeA.js",
"tools:e2e:modeB": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio/wdio.conf.modeB.js",
...
```

Alright, so in each wdio.conf file I specify some variables that may change in each different mode (which both inherit from wdio.conf), however I would like to change what files are run, basically specify that I only want to run the files in modeA's folder for when I run `npm run tools:e2e:modeA`, and only run modeB's files for when I run `npm run tools:e2e:modeB`.

I have attempted to get this done by defining the specs in each conf file as follows:

```
// wdio.conf.js
specs: [
    './wdio/test/specs/browser/**/*.js'
  ],
```

--

```
// wdio.conf.modeA.js
  specs: [
    './wdio/test/specs/browser/modeA/*.js'
  ],
  exclude: [
    './wdio/test/specs/browser/modeB/*.js'
  ]
```

--

```
 // wdio.conf.modeB.js
  specs: [
    './wdio/test/specs/browser/modeB/*.js'
  ],
  exclude: [
    './wdio/test/specs/browser/modeA/*.js'
  ]
```

This however is giving me the following error:

> Error: specs or exclude property should be an array of strings

Which makes no sense, because as you can see, they are an array of strings!

So basically I want to run my wdio tests through my npm commands but only run the mode's folder and not all of them. How can I do this?

PS: I have attempted to separate them into different suites and specify which suite I am running in the npm command in my package.json, however by doing that I am not able to then specify which spec I want to run, which is also something I make use of a lot.

Comment: wdio has command-line arguments, which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

wdio takes command-line arguments. Try this

```
"tools:e2e:modeA": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio/wdio.conf.js --spec ./wdio/test/specs/browser/modeA/*.js",
"tools:e2e:modeB": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio/wdio.conf.js --spec ./wdio/test/specs/browser/modeB/*.js"
```

This way, you need to maintain only one `wdio.conf.js` file

Comment: That is what I have been using, but say there is more than on e spec per mode (which I sortav bundled into suites). This way we are limited to a single spec, which doesn't work for me.

However, I have already opened an issue regarding this problem, and they will work on it :)

Thank you for the help regardless.

Comment: Can you please link to the issue? I'm interested in following this as well!